# Change build tools to 21

Tags: android

```
Warning : Project is building density based multiple APKs but using tools version 19, you should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above to ensure proper packaging of resources
```

Okay this above is the 2 errors that come up in my gradle console when I run my app. The app does not run and just stops. How would I change the build tools to 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio :

- Tools -> Android -> Sdk Manager and install *build-tools 21.0.2*.
- change your *build.gradle* in android block

  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"